# Source generator: CS8795 Partial method 'Class1.GetS2(string)' must have an implementation part because it has accessibility modifiers?

Tags: c#

I created the following project

**ClassLibrary1.csproj**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <LangVersion>10</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" Version="4.6.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Class1.cs**

```csharp
using System;

namespace ClassLibrary1;

public static partial class Class1
{
    public static string GetS(string s)
    {
        var x = GetS2(s);

        return x ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    private static partial string? GetS2(string s); // Error
}
```

**SourceGenerator.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Text;

namespace ClassLibrary1;

[Generator]
public class SourceGenerator : ISourceGenerator
{
    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("namespace ClassLibrary1;");
        sb.AppendLine("public static partial class Class1");
        sb.AppendLine("{");
        sb.AppendLine("    private static partial string? GetS2(string s)");
        sb.AppendLine("    {");
        sb.AppendLine("        return \"Test\";");
        sb.AppendLine("    }");
        sb.AppendLine("}");

        context.AddSource("Class1.g.cs", sb.ToString());
    }

    public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

However, it got the following error?

> Error CS8795  Partial method 'Class1.GetS2(string)' must have an implementation part because it has accessibility modifiers.  ClassLibrary1   C:\source\repos\SourceGeneratorIssue\ClassLibrary1\Class1.cs    14  Active

Comment: Remove the access modifier in Class1 and in the generated code, you are missing a ";" and the namespace.

Comment: Btw: the recommendation is to use incremental source generator instead of source generator.

Comment: Added `;` and namespace (the question is updated). It still got the same error. I cannot remove the access modifier - it got the error of `CS8796 Partial method 'Class1.GetS2(string)' must have accessibility modifiers because it has a non-void return type.`

Comment: Huh, that's weird. So it's wrong to not have one _and_ to have one. So, one of those must be a false positive, no?

Comment: Is that all in one single assembly?

Comment: Btw: I've had that error with LoggerMessage SG and it went away by simply clean & rebuild ... but I think this is different.

Comment: Yes, all three files are in one single project (the test project has only these three files). BTW, i added a line `System.Console.WriteLine("....Test....");` in the `SourceGenerator.Execute()` but I didn't see the message in the output window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes, all three files are in one single project

You need to build the test project to run source generator and you need to run source generator for project to build. Move the source generator to separate project and add it as reference:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\PathToSourceGenLib.csproj"
                  OutputItemType="Analyzer"
                  ReferenceOutputAssembly="false" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Also source generator library must target `netstandard2.0`. From the [Source Generators overview doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview):

> The source generator project needs to target the `netstandard2.0` TFM, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: I moved the class `SourceGenerator` to a new project and referred it in project ClassLibrary1, `<ProjectReference Include="..\SourceGenerator\SourceGenerator.csproj"
      OutputItemType="Analyzer"
      ReferenceOutputAssembly="false"/>`. However, it still got the error.

Comment: @ca9163d9 was not able to repro, projects build successfuly for me (though intellisense does not kick in right away). Try building source generator first "manually".

Comment: Hmm, very strange. I did try to manually build the new project SourceGenerator first.

Comment: @ca9163d9 have you tried building via command line?

Comment: `dotnet build` output:

MSBuild version 17.8.3+195e7f5a3 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  SourceGenerators -> C:\source\repos\SourceGenerators\SourceGenerators\bin\Debug\net8.0\SourceGenerators
  .dll
C:\source\repos\SourceGenerators\ClassLibrary1\Class1.cs(14,36): error CS8795: Partial method 'Class1.GetS2(string)' must have an implementation part because it has accessibility modifiers. [C:\Users\nickw\source\repos\SourceGenerators\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj]

Comment: @ca9163d9 can you please post full [mre] somewhere like github?

Comment: Here is the repo for the code: https://github.com/nkw/SourceGeneratorIssue/tree/master/SourceGenerators

Comment: @ca9163d9 `<ProjectReference Include="..\SourceGenerators\SourceGenerators.csproj" />` - that is wrong. You are missing attributes from the answer. Created a PR. Will try running it myself later

Comment: My bad. Posted an old version of the code. (pushed a commit to fix the `;` issue).  `dotnet build` works. But it failed in Visual Studio:
1>C:\source\repos\SourceGenerators\ClassLibrary1\Class1.cs(14,36,14,41): error CS8795: Partial method 'Class1.GetS2(string)' must have an implementation part because it has accessibility modifiers.

Comment: 1>CSC : warning CS8032: An instance of analyzer ClassLibrary1.SourceGenerator cannot be created from C:\source\repos\SourceGenerators\SourceGenerators\bin\Debug\netstandard2.1\SourceGenerators.dll : Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..

Comment: @ca9163d9 use .NET 8

Comment: changed `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>` to `<TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>`. Still only `dotnet build` works but not Visual Studio.

Comment: @ca9163d9 sorry, my bad. Source generator should be `netstandard2.0`. At least to work in VS =)

Comment: Hmm, I got a lot of strange errors after change it to `netstandard2.0`: 1>C:\source\repos\SourceGenerators\ClassLibrary1\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\.NETStandard,Version=v2.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs(4,20,4,26): error CS0400: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
1>C:\source\repos\SourceGenerators\ClassLibrary1\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\ClassLibrary1.AssemblyInfo.cs(14,12,14,18): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
....

Comment: @ca9163d9 delete bin and obj folders and rebuild.

Comment: It works in VS now after the following updates. 1. Change the source generator project `TargetFramework` to `netstandard2.0`. 2. Add `<ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>` in the `ClassLibrary1` project.

Comment: @ca9163d9 was glad to help. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted one;)